# Why isn't my button animation working in CSS?

Tags: css, button, hover, css-animations

`I follow youtube to build the Button Hover Animations, but it can't work. This button should have a color side from left to right and also change the text color when the cursor point to the button.
In the hover part I put scaleX(1) can,t saw any changes, the button has display the color if I put 2
After I write the button.slide, my cursor didn't work when pointed to the button

```css
button.slide::before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  z-index: -1;
  background-color: var(--accent-color);
  transition: transform, 300ms ease-in-out;
  transform: scaleX(0);
  transform-origin: left;
}

button.slide:hover::before,
button.slide:focus::before {
  transform: scaleX(2);
}

button.slide {
  transition: color 300ms ease-in-out;
  z-index: -1;
}

button.slide:hover,
button.slide:focus {
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<button class="slide">Button</button>
```

Comment: button.slide::before{
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    z-index: -1;
    background-color: var(--accent-color);
    
    
    transition: transform, 300ms ease-in-out;
    transform: scaleX(0);
    transform-origin: left; 
    
}
button.slide:hover::before,
button.slide:focus::before{
     transform: scaleX(2);
}

button.slide{
    transition: color 300ms ease-in-out;
    z-index: -1;
}

button.slide:hover,
button.slide:focus{
    color: white;
}

Comment: [Screen shots don't really help anyone](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/12571484). Can you edit your quesiton and add the code as a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). If it's html/css/js then you can use the [stack snippet editor](https://stackoverflow.blog/2014/09/16/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/)

Comment: Hello and welcome to SO! You can edit your question using the "Edit" link under the question to add the code in text form instead of adding a comment. It is also not very clear what you currently get and what you want, adding an image of what you get and what you want sould help

Comment: position:relative to the button and you have to add a background color to the pseudo-element

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is that what you want?

```css
button.slide::before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  z-index: -1;
  background-color: var(--accent-color);
  transition: transform, 300ms ease-in-out;
  transform: scaleX(0);
  transform-origin: left;
}

button.slide:hover::before,
button.slide:focus::before {
  /* The animation only needs to fill the button */
  transform: scaleX(1);
}

button.slide {
  /* Used to restrict the ::before element */
  position: relative;
  transition: color 300ms ease-in-out;
  /* hover cannot be triggered when zIndex is -1 */
  z-index: 1;
  --accent-color: red
}

button.slide:hover,
button.slide:focus {
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<button class="slide">Button</button>
```